# How to manage user updates and deletions in OIDC and SPA architecture

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, single-page-application, openid-connect

i am making a set of applications that share a common oidc provider (in my control), where the users will be created.

One of my applications is a stateless SPA "meeting" app where you can schedule meetings with other users, and you login purely by an OIDC token.

I am having a hard time thinking a strategy about the following

1. Should the "user" details be stored in the meeting app after a login? So let's say user A exists in the provider, then enters the meeting app. Should i save user A in the meeting app DB?
2. How to handle change of user details? Let's say user A changes name to User B in the provider. Until he logs in again, all the other users see him as User A still in the "contacts" list. What is the usual practice for solving this?
3. How to handle deletions in the provider. I need someway to signal that "deleted in provider -> deleted in app". Should i constantly poll the provider and get any missing users, create a push system, or is this just unneeded?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a very good question and rarely explained well in online articles. Hopefully the below detailed notes help you with your solution. I have answered your questions at the end.

**OAUTH USER DATA**

Typically the core user data such as name, email etc belongs in the Authorization Server. It contains Personally Identifiable Information (PII) and changes are audited there. This is explored in further detail in the [Privacy and GDPR](https://curity.io/resources/learn/privacy-and-gdpr/) article.

**DOMAIN SPECIFIC USER DATA**

This might include fields like a user's application preferences, and you may end up with data similar to this in your APIs:

| Field | Description |
| --- | --- |
| id | A database surrogate key for the user |
| subject | The subject claim from an OAuth access token, which is typically a GUID or something similar |
| archived | A boolean flag set to true when a user is active in the app |
| field 1 | A domain specific value |
| field 2 | A domain specific value |

To get OAuth user data within your applications your APIs can call the Authorization Server's SCIM 2.0 endpoint as described in this [User Management](https://curity.io/resources/learn/managing-users-with-scim/) article.

**AUTHORIZATION AND ROLES**

Interestingly, roles and application specific rights could be stored in either of the above data sources. You may want to start by putting roles in the OAuth data, but for cases where they are very domain specific and change often, I have found that storing them in my own API data works best.

**DOMAIN SPECIFIC USER DATA AND ACCESS TOKENS**

Sometimes you need to include domain specific user data (which might include roles) in access tokens. This [Claims Article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/claims-best-practices/) explains how claims can be looked up from external APIs during token issuance. This typically involves a REST call from the Authorization Server to one or more APIs, providing the subject value for which tokens will be issued.

**CONSISTENT USER IDENTITY IN YOUR APPS**

A user can potentially authenticate in multiple ways, such as default password / corporate login / social login. You may need to use some custom Account Linking logic to ensure that the subject field in the access token gets the same value in all cases. This prevents you ever creating duplicate users within your application.

**USER INFO CHANGES**

These are typically made by end users within an application screen, and your APIs then call SCIM endpoints to update the core OAuth data. A common case is when a user changes their name and / or email, eg if the user gets married. Note that the subject value remains the same after this edit.

**USER ADMINISTRATION**

In scenarios where corporate assets are used, an administrator typically provisions users, either individually or in bulk. This can be done via the SCIM endpoint. In some cases administrator actions may need to save data to both data sources - eg to create a user and set roles + application preferences.

**USER INFO EVENTS**

Sometimes your application needs to know about a user info event, such as new, deleted or changed users. This can be managed via [Event Listeners](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/server-events/index.html), where an extension to the Authorization Server calls back your domain specific APIs when a user edit occurs. When a user is deleted in the OAuth user data you might then update the user's application state to archived.

**DATA MIGRATIONS**

Finally it is worth mentioning that the above also supports migrating to an OAuth architecture or between providers:

- Get a combined view of the user data before migration
- Insert all existing users into the new OAuth system via SCIM
- Update the combined view of the user data with new subject values
- Update your domain specific data with new subject values

**SUMMARY**

So to answer your questions:

1. Aim to avoid this because it adds complexity, though in some cases you may need to denormalise for performance reasons. The OAuth user data should remain the source of truth and the only place where edits occur to PII data.
2. Your meeting app would need to join on the OAuth user data and domain specific user data and present a list. This would probably involve caching a combined view of the user data.
3. See Administrator Events above. Your API should be informed of OAuth user data changes via an event, then your SPA would get current data on the next refresh.

When implemented like this you end up with simple code and a well defined architecture. Some providers may not provide all of these features though, in which case you may need an alternative approach to some areas.